# How to "slide in" content from another HTML file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create an animation that, when the user clicks on a link, shifts the main content of the current page to the left (out of the window) and loads the main content of the page that corresponds with the clicked link (separate HTML), bringing that in from the right.

Here's what I was thinking in terms of JS:

```
$(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a").click(function(){
     var link_id = $(this).attr("id");   
     $("").animate({"margin-left": -$("").outerWidth()},500, function(){                                       
     loadpage(link_id.substr(0,link_id.lastIndexOf("_")), true);
     });
});
```

But I'm not sure as to how to cater this toward what I have ([Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/6eAM4xlYZK)):

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-wrapper"> 
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                   <li><a id="tab1" href="tab1.html">Tab1</a></li>
                    <li><a id="tab2" href="tab2.html"">Tab2</a></li>

                </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "container" -->
    </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->

<div class="container pad-container">

         <h1>Content</h1>
         <p>stuff...</p>
         <p>lorem lorem</p>
         <p>lorem lorem</p>
         <p>lorem lorem</p>
         <p>lorem lorem</p>


    <div class="footer static-footer">
        <div class="container">             

        </div><!-- END: "container" --> 
    </div><!-- END: "footer static-footer" -->  
</div><!-- END: "container pad-container" -->   
</div><!-- END: "custom-wrapper" -->
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
   height:100%;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.custom-wrapper {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
.pad-container{
  padding-top:80px;
  padding-bottom:80px; /*height of the footer plus a little */
}

.static-footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:50px;   /* height of the footer */
   background:#000000;
}
.static-footer .text-muted { /* text on left of footer */
   color: #ffffff; 
   margin-top: 17px;
}
.static-footer .text-primary{ 
   margin-top: -33px;
}
```

Comment: Have gotten anything working yet or is this were you are stuck?

Comment: I'm still stuck - I'm currently trying to update the page with the content that corresponds to the clicked link without having to refresh the page, but it's not working too well.

Comment: Does the content that loads and slides in have to be on a separate page/file? If you put it all in one page and basically treat the main screen as a viewport handling the transition works better.

Comment: Yeah, the way I have it, is that the content for each tab is on its own HTML file - my first problem is just trying to load it without having the page refresh.

Comment: If you need to load without a page refresh start with a ajax request, and have a empty div as a receiver. Fill the new HTML into that receiver. If you are removing the html from the previous "page" you will want to clear that HTML post transition.

Comment: $(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a").click(function() {  
 var page = $(this).attr('href');
 $("#content").load(page); 
}); is what I have, but it is still refreshing

Answer (score 1):

You are still loading the page when you do a .load(page). You will want to do a get like below in your javascript.

```
$.get( "htmlfile.html").done(function( data ) {
     $("#NEW-CONTENT-CONTAINER").append(data);
});
```

and change your HTML to something along these lines

```
<div class="custom-wrapper"> 
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

               <li><a id="tab1" href="tab1.html">Tab1</a></li>
                <li><a id="tab2" href="tab2.html"">Tab2</a></li>

            </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
        </div><!-- END: "container" -->
    </div><!-- END: "container" -->
</div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->

<div id="NEW-CONTENT-CONTAINER"><!-- This container will receive new HTML -->
<div class="container pad-container">
     <h1>Content</h1>
     <p>stuff...</p>
     <p>lorem lorem</p>
     <p>lorem lorem</p>
     <p>lorem lorem</p>
     <p>lorem lorem</p>


<div class="footer static-footer">
    <div class="container">             

    </div><!-- END: "container" --> 
</div><!-- END: "footer static-footer" -->  
</div><!-- END: "container pad-container" -->
</div><!-- END: container container -->   
</div><!-- END: "custom-wrapper" -->
```